# how to add a link like a button into gmail list of emails

Tags: gmail, html-email

How can I prepare my emailm to get the same as I can see in Apple tracking "button"?

Any ideas?

[image: Email list]

[image: html of email list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like I have the answer [gmail go to action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/reference/go-to-action#track_action)