# Click button in email to populate google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email, template-engine

I'm stuck I have done something similar before and it worked but this time round I keep getting a "Sorry, unable to open the file at present." error message.

I want to send an email to a number of participants and once they click on the button in the email my google sheet will update with a simple "Yes", my code is below for the sake completeness I have added everything apologies if it's all a bit much.

GAS code:

```
function sendChallengeEmail() {

  var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzqVFeYC0O1PVHA051UxvrmdJgDJ9gyjhw5X7Lks6j5LGhmRpbCaRLVS38I--ySTLAS/exec'

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NbDbt3IzcXBcZeIa2_XERql4AxnUOQyZDvNRTiaNVXg/edit?pli=1#gid=1386761827");
  const challenges = ss.getSheetByName("Challenges");
  const responses = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
  
  var challengesLen = challenges.getLastRow();
  var challenge = '';
  var challengeCol;
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy").toString();

  for (var i = 1; i <= challengesLen; i++) {
    if (challenges.getRange(i,1).getValue() == date) {
      challenge = challenges.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    }
  }

  for (var j = 1; j <= responses.getLastColumn(); j++) {
    if (responses.getRange(1,j).getValue() == challenge) {
      challengeCol = j;
    }
  }

  var day = challenge.split(" ")[1];
  Logger.log(challenge);
  Logger.log(challengeCol);

  var data = responses.getRange(2,1,responses.getLastRow()-1,13).getValues();
  
  data.forEach(function(row, i) {
    var participant = row[1];
    var participantEmail = row[2]
    var emailSent = row[challengeCol - 2];

    Logger.log(row);
    Logger.log(emailSent);
    Logger.log(challengeCol-1);

    if (emailSent == '') {
      Logger.log(emailSent);
      var emailSentCol = challengeCol - 1;
      var workingRow = i + 2;
    
      var submit = url + "?submit=Yes" + "&challenge=" + challenge + "&r=" + workingRow + "&c=" + challengeCol;
      var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('emailBody');
      templ.participant = participant;
      templ.day = day;
      templ.challenge = challenge;
      templ.submit = submit;

      var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: participantEmail,
        subject: "test",
        htmlBody: message
      });

      var d = new Date();
      responses.getRange(workingRow, emailSentCol).setValue(d);
    };
  });
}

function doGet(e) {
  var answer = e.parameter.submit;
  var workingRow = e.parameter.r;
  var workingCol = e.parameter.c;

  responses.getRange(workingRow, workingCol).setValue(answer);

  var app = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Thank you!")

  return app

}
```

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
    .button {
      border: blue;
      background-color: blue; 
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Hello <?= participant ?> </p>

    <p>You are now on Day <?= day ?> of the challenge!</p>

    <p>Today's challenge is:</p>

    <?= challenge ?>

    <p>Don't forget to submit once you have completed your challenge!</p>

    <a href = <?= submit ?> button id = "btn" onclick ="getElementById('btn').innerHTML='CONGRATULATIONS'" class="button">Challenge completed!</a>

    <p>And finally how about sharing an image of your challenge :)</p>

    <form>
      <label for = '"url " + <?= day ?>'>Enter image url here: </label>
      <input type = "url <?= day ?>" class = textarea id = "url" name = "data[url <?= day ?>]">
      <button type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

I am only logged into one google account I know this has been suggested in other posts.

Comment: Where are you having the error? When clicking the button or just at any moment when trying to access the Sheet?

Comment: When clicking the button

Comment: It might not be your code itself. That is generally an issue of the drive file (the app script file or the Sheet) . I would suggest to make a copy of both and make a test again due to this error generally being linked to the status of the files.

Comment: I've tried creating a new file but still getting the same error.  I've gone back removed the parameters and hard coded values in the doGet but still no luck.

Comment: The code works when I remove the parameters I set i.e. " url + "?submit=Yes" + "&challenge=" + challenge + "&r=" + workingRow + "&c=" + challengeCol;" and hard code the values in the doGet

Comment: Figured it out it was using "&r=" and "&c=" that seemed to be causing the errors changing it to "&wr=" and "&wc=" seems to work.

Comment: As mentioned in your most recent question, I think that you should take some steps back as Gmail and other email clients doesn't support the some HTML tags, like the button tag.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22857716/1595451

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42209748/1595451